# stops horizontal scrolling of section and starts page vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div in my site page that has horizontal scrolling and the entire page has vertical scrolling.when pointer is on particular section it stops the vertical scrolling of page and starts the section horizontal scroll.I have used a function for this.
how can i set that function so that when horizontal scroll of that section reaches at its end then the section scrolling close and web page scrolling start.
How can i achieve this?
I have used the following function for horizontal scrolling of section:-

```
 (function() {
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.getElementById('myDIV').scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myDIV').addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.getElementById('myDIV').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        document.getElementById('myDIV').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        document.getElementById('myDIV').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Measure the width of the div with the horizontal scroll and compare it to the horizontal scroll distance using [jQuery's .scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/). Remember to add the div's width to the scroll distance. When the two are equal, the scrolling reached the div's end. At that point set a flag which is should be continously checked in your scroll function - the flag could determine if the div should scroll or the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {   


  if($("#yourdiv").scrollLeft() + $(window).width() == $("#yourdiv").width()) {
     Your code here
   }
});
```

It should work, but only if your div is larger than the window. If not you should change $(window).width() by $("#mycontainer").width
Hope it will work for you, worked for me in a case almost similar, but i don't know how your page looks like.

Comment: should i put my scroll function in this "Your code here"??

Comment: mhh, i guess u can change your conditions in your if statements by adding mine to yours if ((yours)&(mine)) I cant run test so i 'm just trying to figure it from here sorry. you should try to see this guy by the way :http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/